# Filter specific lines with a given prefix from a file

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I need to get the line before the last of a given prefix on a whole file, which command can I use to do so(sed or any other option)?

For example: (the prefix is the first two numbers of each line: e.g., (16 316) (0 312), etc)

file.txt:

> 16 316 32
>
> 16 316 0
>
> 0 312 9997
>
> 0 312 0
>
> 0 312 21309
>
> 0 312 0
>
> 0 313 10108
>
> 0 313 0
>
> 0 313 32732
>
> 0 313 0
>
> 0 314 9277
>
> 0 314 0
>
> 0 314 19781
>
> 0 314 0
>
> 0 315 7
>
> 0 315 0
>
> 0 315 9380
>
> 0 315 0
>
> 0 315 30388
>
> 0 315 0

The output should be:

> 16 316 32
>
> 0 312 21309
>
> 0 313 32732
>
> 0 314 19781
>
> 0 315 30388

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify the logic of this filtering

Comment: It is something like `for each prefix: select the line before the last`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming those blank lines are not actually in your file.

```
tac file.txt | awk '$1 " " $2 != prefix {getline; print; prefix = $1 " " $2}' | tac
```

```
16 316 32
0 312 21309
0 313 32732
0 314 19781
0 315 30388
```

Reverse the file. When I see a new prefix, print the next line. Then reverse the output.

Comment: I am just curious if we really need `tac` here

Comment: He's asking for the *previous* line. `tac` lets us print out the *next* line

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` should work:

```
awk '$3>0{a[$1,$2]=$0} END{for (i in a) print a[i]}' file
16 316 32
0 312 21309
0 313 32732
0 314 19781
0 315 30388
```